# Summation based on unique entries of two arrays | Speed Issue

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, sum, vectorization

I have 3 arrays of size 803500*1 with the following details:

`Rid`: It can contain any number
`RidID`: It contains elements from 1 to 184 in random order. Each element appears multiple times.
`r`: It contains elements 0,1,2,...12. All elements (except zero) appear nearly 3400 to 3700 times at random indices in this array.

Following may be useful for generating sample data:

```
Rid = rand(803500,1);
RidID = randi(184,803500,1);
r = randi(13,803500,1)-1;  %This may not be a good sample for r as per previously mentioned details?
```

**What I want to do?**
I want to calculate the sum of those entries of `Rid` which correspond to each positive unique entry of `r` and each unique entry of `RidID`.
This may be clearer with the code which I wrote for this problem:

```
RNum = numel(unique(RidID));
RSum = ones(RNum,12); %Preallocating for better speed
for i=1:12
    RperM = r ==i;
    for j = 1:RNum 
        RSum(j,i)  = sum(Rid(RperM & (RidID==j)));
    end
end
```

**Issue:**
My code works but it takes 5 seconds on average on my computer and I have to do this calculation nearly a thousand times. If this time be reduced from 5 seconds to atleast half of it, I'll be very happy. But how do I optimize this? I don't mind if it is made better with vectorization or any better written loop.

I am using MATLAB R2017b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) :

```
u  = unique(RidID);
A = accumarray([RidID r+1], Rid);
RSum = A(u, 2:13);
```

Comment: Omg! This is great! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 2):

This is slower than `accumarray` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58653831/3978545) by rahnema, but using `findgroups` and `splitapply` may save memory.

In your example, there may be thousands of zero-valued elements in the resulting matrix, where a combination of `RidID` and `r` does not occur. In this case a stacked result would be more memory efficient, like so:

```
RidID    | r    | Rid_sum
-------------------------
1        | 1    | 100
2        | 1    | 200
4        | 2    | 85
...
```

This can be achieved with the following code:

```
[ID, rn, RidIDn] = findgroups(r,RidID); % Get unique combo ID for 'r' and 'RidID'
RSum = splitapply( @sum, Rid, ID );     % Sum for each ID
output = table( RidIDn, rn, RSum );     % Nicely formatted table output
% Get rid of elements where r == 0
output( output.rn == 0, : ) = [];
```

You could convert this to the same output as the `accumarray` method, but it's already a slower method...

```
% Convert to 'unstacked' 2D matrix (optional)
RSum = full( sparse( 1:numel(Ridn), 1:numel(rn), RSum ) );
```